# Print the array entity values during Import process

Tags: magento2, import, development, debugging

I need to print the values of the below array during import process.
If I include `print_r();die;` the loading goes indefinite.

Any other way?

```
$entityIn = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides a [`debug()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject.php#L467) method that prevents recursion (which is probably the reason for your infinite loading).

On a single entity you can use it like this:

```
print_r($entity->debug());
```

And on an array of entities:

```
$data = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
print_r($data->debug($arrayOfEntities));
```

Comment: But stil the values is not printing on the screen..it keeps loading if try for a single entity too